# Margin makes Bootstrap 5 column exceed 100vh height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, frontend

I'm trying out Bootstrap 5 with a simple webpage where I have one row with two columns. The left column is fine but the right one is acting funny. The webpage is supposed to be full screen with no scroll. But whenever I put margin in an element inside the right column then the whole column increases in height and goes beyond 100vh/100%. I want `content-right-inner` class to have margin of 50px all around. If I delete `min-height` then all item moves to the top. I want it to be full screen size with margin. How can I do that?

Here's the code:

```css
*, 
*:before, 
*:after {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  margin: 0px;
}

button, 
input {
  overflow: visible;
}

button, 
input, 
optgroup, 
select, 
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.row>* {
  padding-right: 0; 
  padding-left: 0; 
}

.main {
  background-color: green;
  max-height: 100vh;
}


.content-left{
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}


.content-right{
  background: blue;
}
.content-right-inner{
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


.logo p{
  font-family: Lato-Light;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #F7A14C;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.main-content{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.social-box{
  margin: 0 10px 0px 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="main">
        <div class="container-fluid position-relative h-auto p-0 overflow-hidden">
            <div class="row">

                <section class="content-left col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="inner-container">
                  <p>Boom Boom</p>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <section class="content-right col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="content-right-inner">
                        <div class="logo text-center">
                            <p>test</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="main-content">
                            <h1>Lorem Ipsum!</h1>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsumsdfafafafafa!</p>
                            <button>Lorem Ip</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="social-icons">
                            <div class="social-box">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="social-box">
                                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="social-box">
                                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="social-box">
                                <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Weird issue. Try adding `min-height: -webkit-fill-available;` in your `.content-right-inner`, as described [here](https://allthingssmitty.com/2020/05/11/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/). Does this result in the desired behavior?

Comment: @Tommy No nothing. Do you think it's because of B5? As it is an alpha release, may be it has some issues?

Comment: Idk, you should wait some time and if nobody replies you could open an Issue in Bootstrap.

Comment: @Zak Could you please use padding instead of margin?

Comment: @PrakashRajotiya I did. But then the elements inside ignores the padding and starts from the beginning of the outside container. But nevermind. I have found a fix for it. Please check below answer. I'll close the thread tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix for the issue. Putting margin all around and especially at the bottom made the container exceed it's height of 100vh. To fix it I just used `calc()` in `.content-right-inner`.

Here's the code:

```
.content-right-inner{
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 95vh;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

I guess that just deducts the extra height which came from a margin of 50px.